# select max value and another column

Tags: sql

```
id    value
2      20
1      30
3      15
5      25
```

I have this table and want to get max value and id. When i use `select id,max(value)` i've got `2,30` but the right answer is `1,30`. I really need to get your attention. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't ask SQL questions without tagging them with the DBMS you are using. From your description it seems that you are using MySQL, because `select id,max(value) from some_table` is invalid SQL, but MySQL is known for silently applying `ANY_VALUE` on `id` in this situation, thus just grabbing some unrelated ID. Set the SQL mode to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in order to avoid this undesired behavior.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row `(4,30)` to the above sample data?

Comment: This is imposible to double id in same value in this table. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, value from `table` order by value desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using subquery

```
select * from tablename
where value in (select max(value) from tablename)
```

Comment: That should be `where value =`, because the subquery cannot return more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Use  subquery

```
select * 
from t 
where value = (select max(value) from table)
```

From the @Thorsten comments i noted that 1st query will return all ties of max value.

Or you can use order by with limit if it is mysql

```
select *  
from table 
order by value desc 
limit 1
```

And 2nd query will return only the single row of highest value

Comment: @made artama: There is a difference between the two queries, though. The first gives you all rows that share the maximum value. The second just picks one row arbitrarily from those with the highest value. So make up your mind what result you want to see in case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE value=(SELECT 
             MAX(value) as value 
             FROM tablename)
```

You can check this query. Giving result according your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 id,max(value) FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY max(value) desc
```